# Open immersion of schemes and pullbacks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, pullback

Assume $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of schemes and take $U_1,U_2$ open subsets of $X$ s.t. $f(U_i)\subset V$ for some open subset $V\subset Y$. I would like to show the induced map $U_1\times_V U_2\to X\times_Y X $ is an open immersion.

I think I have an idea on how to prove the statement, but I'm not sure it works. The situation can be represented diagrammatically as a cube where two faces of the cubes are pullbacks : [image: pullback cube two pullbacks the one with U_1, U_2, V, and the one of X,X,Y, where the maps between the squares are inclusions U_i in X, V in Y, and the induced map between the pullbacks]

Essentially, you have two (pullback) squares

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
U_1\times_V U_2 @>>> U_1 @. X\times_Y X @>>> X\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
U_2 @>>> V @. X@>>> Y
\end{CD}

And you have maps between the squares making the whole cube commutes, given by the inclusions $U_i\to X$, $V\to Y$ and the induced map $U_1\times_V U_2 \to X\times_YX$. My reasoning was that since each map $U_i\to X$ and $V\to Y$ is an open immersion, and open immersions are stable under base change, *surely* the resulting map $U_1\times_V U_2 \to X\times_YX$ is also an open immersion. But while I can prove these two separate facts, I cannot actually reach the desired conclusion. I also feel I might be able to arrive at the desired conclusion using associativity of pullbacs in a way but I don't know. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that from your assumptions, the projection  $U_i\times_Y V\to U_i$ is an isomorphism of $V$-schemes. Hence you have maps $$U_1\times_V U_2\simeq (U_1\times_Y V)\times_V(U_2\times_Y V)$$
$$
\simeq
(U_1\times_Y U_2)\times_Y V\hookrightarrow U_1\times_Y U_2\hookrightarrow U_1\times_Y X\hookrightarrow X\times_Y X$$
Here the two first maps are isomorphisms in any category and the three remaining maps are open immersions because open immersions are stable under base change.

Comment: @DamianRössler Thanks for your comment ! At first I was convinced (I still am) but I tried writing everything down properly and there's something I'm having trouble with. For instance the right most map $U_1\times_YX\to X\times_YX$ being an open immersion, because it's the pullback of an open immersion. Which map exactly ? I don't seem to be able to explicitly write it as the pullback of a known immersion.

Comment: The last arrow is the arrow $U_1\times_X(X\times_Y X)\to X\times_Y X$, so the pull back of the immersion $U_1\to X$ by the first projection $X\times_Y X\to X.$ You have to use the fact that  $U_1\times_X(X\times_Y X)\simeq U_1\times_Y X.$